# Prevent expand when firing back end code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

i'm using jquery to collapse and expand a some div tags in my page..

my problem is that if i have a div that is collapsed and i fire an event in the back end code the page refreshes and the div expands... does anyone have any idea how can i fix this?

note that i'm using asp.net with vb.net

```
<div class="content-module-heading cf">
   <h3 class="fl">Table of content to send</h3>
   <span class="fr expand-collapse-text">Click to collapse</span>
   <span style="display: none;" class="fr expand-collapse-text initial-expand">Click to expand</span>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

//Content boxes expand/collapse
$(".initial-expand").hide();

$("div.content-module-heading").click(function(){
    $(this).next("div.content-module-main").slideToggle();

    $(this).children(".expand-collapse-text").toggle();
});

 });
```

Comment: use local storage or cookies to store div hidden or not.

Comment: @TusharGupta i did not get what you mean.. i updated my question with my jquery can you please tell me how to do what you suggested?